# "Заложенная в драматургии мысль" и "мотивации" без указания чего - такое возможно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, жаргон

> Мотивации действующих лиц пьесы бывают настолько ясны, что дают театру
>   на протяжении веков возможность обращаться и обнаруживать всё больше
>   трактовок заложенной в драматургии мысли.

Comment: A также под вопросом: 1. Слово *обращаться* без указания к чему. 2. Словосочетание "трактовка мысли"

Comment: Мерси боку, *обращаться* прозевала!

Comment: К чему множ. число? «Мотивация действующих лиц пьесы бывает настолько ясна» и т.д.

Comment: Всё это может оказаться актёрским сленгом, но все вопросы/ответы/комменты он внимательно читает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, мотивация должна употребляться в ед. ч. Под мотивацией может пониматься совокупность доводов для обоснования чего-либо либо совокупность мотивов (побудительных причин). Мне кажется, требуется указывать мотивация чего, но в последнее время приходится слышать выражения типа "чья-либо мотивация" (очевидно, под влиянием иностранных языков). Насколько это грамотно — не берусь судить.

Но совершенно непонятно, как ясность мотивации дает простор для множества трактовок. Скорее наоборот: чем ситуация яснее, тем меньше трактовок.